# How to get info (mean,std) out of normplot in matlab?

Tags: statistics, probability, probability-distribution-function

Lets say we have the following data and then we have a normplot:

```
load census;
h=normplot(cdate);
[mean std]=normfit(cdate);
```

I know i can get the mean(1890) and std(62.0484) of the data using normfit fxn, but thats not what i need.

As you can see in the plot, the straight red line is the ideal for the data.[image]

i want to know the mean and std of the line.

I think we can do it from the slope of the line.. using handles of the figure probably with h(3).Xdata and Ydata.., but somehow i cant figure it out.

Can you please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Random variables have means and standard deviations. Can you clarify what you mean by the mean and st.d. of a line?

Comment: I mean , the mean and std values of a normal distribution that would give me this red line.

Comment: That doesn't help. You already know the mean and std that produced that line. Do you mean, given a line (slope and y-intercept), find the mean and std of the underlying distribution?

Comment: no we dont know the mean and std that produced the line. we know the mean and std that produced the curve.  
yes find the underlying distribution of the line.. check below for the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just made a few modifications to the normplot program to give the reference data as output as well. xexp is the reference data and yperexp is the reference probability 
(reference is the red line data). You can copy paste the whole code below and run it

```
function [h,xexp,yperexp] = nplot(x)

%   Copyright 1993-2010 The MathWorks, Inc. 


if size(x,1)==1
x = x';
end
[n, m] = size(x);

[sx,originds] = sort(x);

minx  = min(sx(:));
maxx  = max(sx(:));
if isnan(minx) % Data all NaNs, setting arbitrary limits.

minx = 0;
maxx = 1;
end
range = maxx-minx;

if range>0
minxaxis  = minx-0.025*range;
maxxaxis  = maxx+0.025*range;
else
minxaxis  = minx - 1;
maxxaxis  = maxx + 1;
end

% Use the same Y vector if all columns have the same count.
if (~any(isnan(x(:))))
eprob = ((1:n)' - 0.5)./n;
else
nvec = sum(~isnan(x));
eprob = repmat((1:n)', 1, m);
eprob = (eprob-.5) ./ repmat(nvec, n, 1);
eprob(isnan(sx)) = NaN;
end

y  = norminv(eprob,0,1);

minyaxis  = norminv(0.25 ./n,0,1);
maxyaxis  = norminv((n-0.25) ./n,0,1);


p     = [0.001 0.003 0.01 0.02 0.05 0.10 0.25 0.5...
     0.75 0.90 0.95 0.98 0.99 0.997 0.999];

label = {'0.001','0.003', '0.01','0.02','0.05','0.10','0.25','0.50', ...
     '0.75','0.90','0.95','0.98','0.99','0.997', '0.999'};

tick  = norminv(p,0,1);

q1x = prctile(x,25);
q3x = prctile(x,75);
q1y = prctile(y,25);
q3y = prctile(y,75);
qx = [q1x; q3x];
qy = [q1y; q3y];


dx = q3x - q1x;
dy = q3y - q1y;
slope = dy./dx;
centerx = (q1x + q3x)/2;
centery = (q1y + q3y)/2;
maxx = max(x);
minx = min(x);
maxy = centery + slope.*(maxx - centerx);
miny = centery - slope.*(centerx - minx);
yinter = centery - slope.*(centerx);

mx = [minx; maxx];
my = [miny; maxy];


% Plot data and corresponding reference lines in the same color,
% following the default color order.  Plot reference line first, 
% followed by the data, so that data will be on top of reference line.
newplot();
hrefends = line(mx,my,'LineStyle','-.','Marker','none');
hrefmid = line(qx,qy,'LineStyle','-','Marker','none');
hdat = line(sx,y,'LineStyle','none','Marker','+');
if m==1
    set(hdat,'Color','b');
    set([hrefends,hrefmid],'Color','r');
end
if nargout>0
    h = [hdat;hrefmid;hrefends];

% Compute position to display.
yper = normcdf(y,0,1);
yperexp = normcdf(polyval([slope,yinter],sx));
xexp = polyval([1/slope,-yinter/slope],y);

end


set(gca,'YTick',tick,'YTickLabel',label);
set(gca,'YLim',[minyaxis maxyaxis],'XLim',[minxaxis maxxaxis]);
xlabel(getString(message('stats:probplot:Data')));
ylabel(getString(message('stats:probplot:Probability')));
title(getString(message('stats:probplot:NormalProbPlot')));

grid on;
box off;


for i=1:m
    % Set custom data cursor on data.
    hB = hggetbehavior(hdat(i),'datacursor');
    set(hB,'UpdateFcn',{@normplotDatatipCallback,slope(i),yinter(i)});
    % Disable datacursor on reference lines.
    hB = hggetbehavior(hrefends(i),'datacursor');
    set(hB,'Enable',false);
    hB = hggetbehavior(hrefmid(i),'datacursor');
    set(hB,'Enable',false);
    if m>1
        setappdata(hdat(i),'group',i);
    end
    setappdata(hdat(i),'originds',originds(:,i));
end



function datatipTxt = normplotDatatipCallback(obj,evt,slope,yinter)

target = get(evt,'Target'); 
ind = get(evt,'DataIndex');
pos = get(evt,'Position');

x = pos(1);
y = pos(2);

% Compute position to display.
yper = normcdf(y,0,1);
yperexp = normcdf(polyval([slope,yinter],x));
xexp = polyval([1/slope,-yinter/slope],y);

% Get the original row number of the selected point.
originds = getappdata(target,'originds');
origind = originds(ind);

% Get the group number, which is set if more than one.
group = getappdata(target,'group');

% Generate text to display.
datatipTxt = {
sprintf('%s: %s',getString(message('stats:probplot:Data')),num2str(x)),...
sprintf('%s: %s',getString(message('stats:probplot:Probability')),num2str(yper)),...
''
};
datatipTxt{end+1} = sprintf('%s: %s',...
getString(message('stats:probplot:Observation')),num2str(origind));
if ~isempty(group)
datatipTxt{end+1} = sprintf('%s: %s',...
    getString(message('stats:probplot:Group')),num2str(group));
end

datatipTxt{end+1} = '';
datatipTxt{end+1} = sprintf('%s %s: %s',...
getString(message('stats:probplot:ReferenceLine')),...
getString(message('stats:probplot:Data')),...
num2str(xexp));
datatipTxt{end+1} = sprintf('%s %s: %s',...
getString(message('stats:probplot:ReferenceLine')),...
getString(message('stats:probplot:Probability')),...
num2str(yperexp));
```

Comment: Perfect ! .. Thankyou so much